# C# await on GUI thread and catch exceptions WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task, ui-thread

I am using MVVM Light and there is a interface IDialogService which for used for showing dialogs. This interface has been implemented in App.xaml.cs

One specific method is interesting:

```
Task<bool> ShowMessage(string message, string title, string buttonConfirmText, string buttonCancelText, Action<bool> afterHideCallback);
```

The method is implemented as:

```
        public Task<bool> ShowMessage(string message, string title, string buttonConfirmText,
        string buttonCancelText,
        Action<bool> afterHideCallback)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var style = new Style(typeof(MessageBox));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MessageBox.OkButtonContentProperty, buttonConfirmText));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(MessageBox.CancelButtonContentProperty, buttonCancelText));
            var result = MessageBox.Show(_GetActiveWindow(), message, title,
                MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxImage.Question, style) == MessageBoxResult.OK;
            if (afterHideCallback != null) afterHideCallback(result);
            return result;
```

Where `_currentTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();` is defined in `OnStartup`

So usually we should call this method with await in front to get boolean value:

```
    var result = await  DialogService.ShowMessage(
                        Resources.Areyousure,Resources.Warning, 
                        Resources.Yes, Resources.No, null);
```

So far so good. Now I have a wrapper method to execute code and catch exceptions and then show messaged box with error.

```
    public bool TryCatchExecution(Action action, string successMessage = null)
    {
        try
        {
            action();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(successMessage))
                DialogService.ShowMessage(successMessage, Resources.Success);
            return true;
        }
        catch (LogException ex)
        {
            DialogService.ShowError(ex.Error.LogMessage, Resources.Error, Resources.OK, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DialogService.ShowError(ex.Message, Resources.Error, Resources.OK, null);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And now I have a problem. If I use like sample A the GUI thread is blocked at the line `var result =  DialogService.ShowMessage` . But if I use as in sample B the GUI thread in not blocked, message box shown and everything works like it should. Until I get an exception. The exception is unhanded by code. The error is "A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll" and application crashes. As I have been reading this has something to do with SynchronizationContext.

```
    //Sample A
    private void ExecuteDeleteCommand()
    {
         TryCatchExecution(() =>
            {
                var result =  DialogService.ShowMessage(
                    Resources.Areyousure,
                    Resources.Warning,
                    Resources.Yes,
                    Resources.No, null).Result;
                if (!result) return;

                _datalayer.DeleteField(FieldSelected);
                Refresh();
                FieldEdit = new MsgSqlFieldMapping();
                RaisePropertyChanged("SqlRepository");
                DialogService.ShowMessage(Resources.OperationSucceeded, Resources.Success);
            });
    }

    //Sample B
    private void ExecuteDeleteCommand()
    {
        TryCatchExecution(async () =>
        {
            var result =await DialogService.ShowMessage(
                Resources.Areyousure,
                Resources.Warning,
                Resources.Yes,
                Resources.No, null);
            if (!result) return;

            _datalayer.DeleteField(FieldSelected);
            Refresh();
            FieldEdit = new MsgSqlFieldMapping();
            RaisePropertyChanged("SqlRepository");
            await DialogService.ShowMessage(Resources.OperationSucceeded, Resources.Success);
        });
    }
```

Please help me to understand whats happening here and how to deal with it.

THNX a lot.

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I am using .net4.5 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to `async void` - specifically, by passing an `async` lambda as an argument of type `Action`, you're creating an `async void` method. One of the [problems with `async void` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is that you can't catch exceptions (at least, not the normal way).

To resolve this, create an overload of your helper method that takes the [async equivalent of `Action`, which is `Func<Task>`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html):

```
public async Task<bool> TryCatchExecution(Func<Task> action, string successMessage = null)
{
    try
    {
        await action();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(successMessage))
            DialogService.ShowMessage(successMessage, Resources.Success);
        return true;
    }
    catch (LogException ex)
    {
        DialogService.ShowError(ex.Error.LogMessage, Resources.Error, Resources.OK, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DialogService.ShowError(ex.Message, Resources.Error, Resources.OK, null);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks with solution. There is a small problem. I was already examined this solution. The problem is that after changing method signature I needed to alter about 200 other methods.

Comment: @Gintaras: Don't *change* your method; just *add* this one.